# User authorization error 422 "Unexpected signature"

Tags: http, quickblox

I tried to run user authorization from my c# app to https://api.quickblox.com/auth.json. I got on response error code **422 Unexpected signature. Does anyone know what this means or how to debug the error?

I sent the following string as a parameter:

```
{  "application_id": "MYAPPID",  
   "auth_key": "MYAUTHKEY",  
   "timestamp": "1394632995",  
   "nonce": "487",  
   "signature": "6bf130657ee04e68ff41a08ace44480f90b49f11",  
   "user": {    
      "login": "mylogin",    
      "password": "mypassword"  
   }
}
```

Comment: There is no enough information. What is the request you perform. What parameters are fill with the request. Do you transmit cookies ? etc...

Comment: Solved. For user auhentication I must add to body string user[login] and user[password] parameters. I can't found this in SDK documentation.

Comment: If you format your solution into an answer and then select it as an answer you will assist others who may have the same issue and let the community know that the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 2):

It means that your **signature** value is wrong;

More info about signature generation is here http://quickblox.com/developers/Authentication_and_Authorization#Signature_generation

Some examples for C# you can find here
https://github.com/QuickBlox/SimpleSample-BackgroundMode-WindowsPhone7/blob/master/QuickBloxSDK-Silverlight/QuickBlox.cs

```
StringBuilder signature = new StringBuilder();
signature.Append("application_id");
signature.Append("=");
signature.Append(this.ApplicationId.ToString());
signature.Append("&");
signature.Append("auth_key");
signature.Append("=");
signature.Append(this.AuthenticationKey);
signature.Append("&");
signature.Append("nonce");
signature.Append("=");
signature.Append(randomResult);
signature.Append("&");
signature.Append("timestamp");
signature.Append("=");
signature.Append(ts.ToString());


byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(this.AuthenticationSecret);
this.Encode(signature.ToString(),key)

private  string Encode(string input, byte[] key)
{
    HMACSHA1 myhmacsha1 = new HMACSHA1(key);
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
    return myhmacsha1.ComputeHash(stream).Aggregate("", (s, e) => s + String.Format("{0:x2}", e), s => s);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the first link and `Encode` function help.